# Angularjs: como trabalhar com controllers separados por arquivos

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Utilizo um service para fazer com que cada rota faça 3 requisições http.get: uma para o conteúdo que o servidor vai gerar em uma parte da página, para um arquivo js que contém o seu controller e para um arquivo css.

O meu problema ocorre quando eu carrego esse script que contém o controller, e nada acontece na minha página solicitada.

Exemplo do meu código:

App.js

```
angular.module('main', [myModulesHere...])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/about', {
        template: '',
        controller: 'aboutLoad'
    })        
})

.controller('aboutLoad', function($scope, myCustomHttpService) {

    // Aqui o método getRoute vai tratar-se de fazer a
    // requisição http.get, e enviar o conteúdo do servidor
    // para o ng-view quando tudo for completado

    myCustomHttpService.getRoute('/about', {
        js: './public/view/main/js/AboutController.js',
        css: './public/view/main/css/about.css'
    });
})
```

AboutController.js

```
angular.module('main').controller('AboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = 'Página: Sobre Nós';
});
```

AboutView.php

```
<div ng-controller="AboutController">
    <h2 ng-bind="myText"></h2>
</div>
```

Quando carrego a página index do site, apenas o App.js é carregado. Esses arquivos são solicitados quando eu mudo de página usando as routes do Angular.

PS: O meu objetivo é criar um site que o usuário não precise carregar o header sempre que ele mudar de página, apenas obter o conteúdo requisitado por página. São exemplos: Disqus, Play Store da Google, Facebook, YouTube, e outros.

Comment: Então no index.html, você quer deixar apenas o header com um menu e em baixo do header, quer carregar os conteudo dinamicos é isso?

Comment: Se você está definindo o controller na própria rota, não precisa usar o ng-controller na div. Porém, utilize o mesmo nome do controller na declaração da rota. Veja se isso resolve.

Comment: É isso mesmo, Marcos Souza. O problema que está acontecendo é que o controller de cada rota não está sendo executado. Ou seja, quando o arquivo do meu servidor é carregado e passado para a ng-view, todas as diretivas que estão no meu código não estão sendo interpretadas pelo controller (que também é carregado dinamicamente).

Comment: use o oclazyload e seja feliz, porque reinventar a roda?

Comment: Diogo, me recomendaram o RequireJS. Ele já é o suficiente para carregar os controllers que estão em arquivos separados, ou você me recomendaria, mesmo assim, o ocLazyLoad? Se sim, quais as vantagens dele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan utilize o [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) para carregar seu arquivos `on demand` (Chamando apenas quando precisa utilizar aqueles arquivos).

Utilize o lazyload no resolve assim ele cuidara de carregar toda as suas dependências da rota antes de renderizar a sua view.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad']);
  app.config(routes);

  function routes($stateProvider) {
    var about = {
      name: 'about',
      url: '/about',
      controller: 'AboutController',
      controllerAs: 'aboutCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'about.html',
      resolve: {
        lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              files: ['aboutController.js', 'about.css']
            });
        }
      }
    };

    $stateProvider.state(about);
  }

}());
```

Comment: Opa! Obrigado pela resposta, Ralfting. Posso implementar isso aí na minha estrutura usando RequireJS, ou acha melhor eu refazer tudo usando apenas o ocLazyload?

Comment: @RenanCoelho não vejo necessidade de utilizar o RequireJS já que o oclazyload carrega arquivos `js/css/templates`, então não vejo a necessidade.