# Angularjs: como evitar a chamada da rota no primeiro carregamento da página

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu preciso fazer com que a página seja totalmente carregada, sem chamar nenhuma rota, quando o usuário acessar pelo link direto. O problema ocorre quando a página carrega, o Angular simplesmente lê o caminho do URL e chama a rota. As rotas só poderão ser chamadas quando eu clicar em algum botão.

Como é possível evitar a chamada da rota após o carregamento da página?

Comment: Como esta o carregamento do seu app e dos scripts no seu html? Você esta usando `ng-app` ou inicializando o app manualmente com `angular.bootstrap()`?

Comment: Ainda estou usando `ng-app`. Na medida em que estou desenvolvendo o projeto, vou precisar utilizar `angular.bootstrap` para iniciar o app manualmente. E o carregamento dos scripts está sendo on-demand. Ou seja, o usuário carrega apenas os arquivos app.s e routes.js para a configuração do app, e conforme ele navega nas páginas, outros arquivos vão sendo carregados juntamente com seus controllers.

Comment: Hm, como vc faz esse carregamento on-demand? Usa RequireJS?

Comment: Conforme seu usuário navega ele vai carregando apps, router e controllers? Se é isso, como está fazendo? Qual componente de rotas está usando?

Comment: Estou usando o ocLazyLoader.

Comment: Caraca, não conhecia esse ocLazyLoad, não vou conseguir te ajudar nessa questão mas obrigado por ter comentado sobre esse componente.

Comment: Opa! Feliz em ajudar! Dê uma olhada na minha última pergunta feita aqui no Stack [Angularjs: como trabalhar com controllers separados por arquivos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160791/angularjs-como-trabalhar-com-controllers-separados-por-arquivos). Foi lá que um cara me indicou o ocLazyLoader. Mas de qualquer forma, obrigado. Ainda vou continuar atrás dessa questão.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tanto pesquisar, não obtive sucesso. Mas resolvi criar meu método simples que solucionou o meu problema e sei que pode ajudar quem tiver essa mesma dúvida.

Código:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

.run(function($rootScope) {

   // privates
   var isPageLoaded = false;

   // constructs
   $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
      if (!isPageLoaded) {
         isPageLoaded = true;
         event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
});
```

Agora o seu carregamento da página será completo, sem a necessidade de uma segunda requisição feita pela rota. Basta clicar em algum botão contento o caminho de uma rota que ela irá ser acionada normalmente, apenas não quando a página é carregada pelo URL.